# Translate strings that are not in default language TO default language?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a Drupal site running in English by default but also supports French, however some fields are input from a feed and I need to translate those values into English.

It's about 4-5 values that are in the feed, that get used in one field for a couple node types.

Is there any way to translate "non-default" language strings to their "default" language versions?